# How do electric carbon monoxide detectors work?

Tags: aircraft-systems

How does the electric carbon monoxide detector in cabin or cockpit on aircraft work?

Comment: You may find the Wikipedia article on [Carbon monoxide detector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_monoxide_detector) informative. That article mostly talks about home detectors, but the technology is the same.

Comment: Related, "[Carbon Monoxide Detectors](https://www.avweb.com/news/aeromed/186016-1.html)" on AVweb.

Comment: The amount of fire-on-aircraft quesitons you are asking is worrisome :-)

Comment: I am currently working on description and operation of fire detention systems for my first shop rotation.

Comment: @MyatKhant: Good to know you're not an aspiring arsonist! :-P

Answer (score 2):

There are three major types of carbon monoxide senors.

- Biomimetic: A gel changes color when it absorbs carbon
  monoxide.
- Metal oxide semiconductor: When the chip's circuit detects
  carbon monoxide, electrical resistance decreases, and this 
  triggers an alarm.
- Electrochemical: Electrodes immersed in a chemical solution
  sense changes in current when they come into contact with carbon
  monoxide, and this change triggers the alarm.